# How can I insert an element in a specific row in a GridLayout?

Tags: android, xamarin

I am programming an Android app and I need to create a grid with 4 rows. In each row I need to put different elements. The problem is that I can't insert the elements in the desired row. In my example the ImageButton is inserted in the first row although I want to insert it in the second row. Does anyone have a solution how to do this with XML ? Thank you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
      android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:columnCount="2"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:rowCount="4"
       tools:context=".GridXMLActivity"
       tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="56dp"
       tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">
       
        <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
           android:layout_width="160dp"
           android:layout_height="90dp"
           android:layout_row="2"
           android:layout_gravity="left|top"
           android:src="@drawable/scene1" />
       
 
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/grid-layout)

> Notice in the XML above, each TextView does not specify a row or
> column. When these are not specified, the GridLayout assigns each
> child view in order

cells are filled L-R, T-B in a horizontal layout, or T-B,L-R in a vertical layout

or you can specify explicit row and column values

```
<TextView
        android:text="Cell 0"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0" />
```